# Xcode 6.3 warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6.3

I am getting this below warning after I update the Xcode to 6.3 version.

> Using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of
>   floating point type

Example

```
 CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(15.0f, 25.0f);
 CGPoint endPoint   = CGPointMake(10.0f, 20.0f);
 CGFloat centerDiff = abs(startPoint.y - endPoint.y);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`abs()` expects integers. You should use `fabs(value)` for floating point values